# Changing a Powershell Script into a Python Script

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to convert a powershell script into a python script, can someone explain how this command line works?

Also can someone explain me the python command to do the same thing?

```
get-childitem \\$server\siglocal$\MACAutoTicket -recurse | where {$_.name -like "MACAutoTicket.$date.$server.macautoticket.*"} |
```

Comment: os (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) `os.listdir('your\directory\')` lists the names of the items in a directory. you can then iterate over / filter that list. Just the names though, not the actual files.

Comment: thank a lot. this is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explaining the Powershell:

```
get-childitem \\$server\siglocal$\MACAutoTicket -recurse
```

This will list all the files including subdirectories on a remote computer that's passed as variable `$server`.

The results are then passed to a filter

```
where {$_.name -like "MACAutoTicket.$date.$server.macautoticket.*"}
```

Which in turn will include only such files that match a specific name pattern:

```
"MACAutoTicket.$date.$server.macautoticket.*"
```

The file name should contain string literals and likely a date obtained from `$date` and the server's name obtained from the forementioned `$server`.

In order to proceed with Python conversion, find out where `$server` and `$date` are obtained. Maybe they are script parameters or read from some configuration file.

Python's [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) looks like a good starting point for creating similar a filter for file names.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found this module os.walk that reiterates through the directory. How would I go about adding a filter in this. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

vonpryz has a good answer, I'd add to it a little bit.

`name` is a property that the child items all have; this script only looks at name.  If you want a list of all the properties, running the command `get-childitem \\$server\siglocal$\MACAutoTicket | get-member` will list all the properties available to you.

You probably already know this, but `-recurse` will look at all the child directories and get their content as well.  Keep in mind that the `get-childitem` command is more than just a "dir" command - it can also get child items from a parent in the registry, such as HKLM.

The question is somewhat broad so I'll also add an explanation of the pipe `|` character.  This takes the output from one command and makes it the input to the next command.  You can string together a long list of commands doing this where the next cmdlet takes the output from the previous, does its processing, spits out the result, and then is processed by the next cmdlet.